# Line break based on symbol in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-2014

Hi I am new to SSRS Report i have to apply line break on table column field based on some symbol(~) . I dont know how to write expression for this

```
    Medline Industries, Inc.~email inv to:
    vendorinvoices@medline.com~Attn: A/P Priority
    A~PO Box 876~Mundelein IL 60060-0876~USA~~

    **To change like below based on ~:**

    Medline Industries, Inc.
    email inv to:vendorinvoices@medline.com
    Attn: A/P Priority A
    PO Box 876
    Mundelein IL 60060-0876
    USA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myself find out answer using replace expression to achieve my output

My Expression Code:

```
=Replace(Fields!Calc_BillToAddressList.Value,"~",vbCrLf)
```